# Powershell - Why isn't the exception thrown by Set-CASMailbox getting caught?

Tags: exception, powershell, try-catch, exchange-server-2010, throw

I have a Powershell script that is run on a Windows 2008 R2 server with Exchange Server 2010 console installed on it. The script, **pmduaactivesync.ps1**, is run from Task scheduler, so it has to be called using a weird command rather than just calling it directly. Here is how it is run:

```
powershell -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v14\bin\exshell.psc1" -exec bypass -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Exchange.ps1'; &'C:\dev\csom\pmduaactivesync.ps1'"
```

The script is being run as a service account, and that account has all the access it needs to make changes in the Exchange environment.

Now, in the script, at one point I am trying to set the *Exchange ActiveSync* attribute on a mailbox to True. Here is that part of the code

```
# Try setting ActiveSync to true
try {
  Set-CASMailbox -Identity $tempUsername -ActiveSyncEnabled $true 
  if ($?) {
    # Set ASChangeValue to 1 (to be used when updating SP List)
    $ASChangeValue="1"
  } else {
    throw $error[0].Exception
  }
} catch {
  Write-Host "Exception caught with 'Set-CASMailbox -Identity $tempUsername -ActiveSyncEnabled $true' command." -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
  $ASChangeValue="8"
}
```

In the script, I'm also creating a transcript using the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet.

Here is my problem. The `Set-CASMailbox` cmdlet is throwing an error, shown below:

```
WARNING: The cmdlet extension agent with the index 1 has thrown an exception in OnComplete(). The exception is: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ExchangePrincipal.get_ServerFullyQualifiedDomainName()

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.Initialize(MapiStore linkedStore, LogonType logonType, 
ExchangePrincipal owner, DelegateLogonUser delegateUser, Object identity, OpenMailboxSessionFlags flags, 
GenericIdentity auxiliaryIdentity)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateMailboxSession>b__10(MailboxSession 
mailboxSession)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.InternalCreateMailboxSession(LogonType logonType, 
ExchangePrincipal owner, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, IAccountingObject budget, Action`1 
initializeMailboxSession, InitializeMailboxSessionFailure initializeMailboxSessionFailure)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.CreateMailboxSession(LogonType logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner,
 DelegateLogonUser delegateUser, Object identity, OpenMailboxSessionFlags flags, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String 
clientInfoString, PropertyDefinition[] mailboxProperties, IList`1 foldersToInit, GenericIdentity auxiliaryIdentity, 
IAccountingObject budget)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.ConfigurableOpen(ExchangePrincipal mailbox, MailboxAccessInfo 
accessInfo, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, LogonType logonType, PropertyDefinition[] 
mailboxProperties, InitializationFlags initFlags, IList`1 foldersToInit, IAccountingObject budget)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.OpenAsSystemService(ExchangePrincipal mailboxOwner, CultureInfo 
cultureInfo, String clientInfoString)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.MailboxLoggerFactory.XsoMailer.Log(AdminLogMessageData data, 
LogMessageDelegate logMessage)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.AdminLogProvisioningHandler.OnComplete(Boolean succeeded, Exception e)

   at Microsoft.Exchange.Provisioning.ProvisioningLayer.OnComplete(Task task, Boolean succeeded, Exception exception)
```

I'm not 100% on this, but since the error is referencing "The cmdlet extension agent with the index **1**" I ran `Get-CmdletExtensionAgent` to see what that might be. After running the command, assuming I'm reading it correctly, it is referencing the **Query Base DN Agent**.

```
>Get-CmdletExtensionAgent | Format-Table Name, Enabled, Priority
Name                                Enabled    Priority
----                                -------    --------
Admin Audit Log Agent                  True         255
Query Base DN Agent                    True           1
Rus Agent                              True           2
Mailbox Resources Management Agent     True           3
Provisioning Policy Agent              True           4
OAB Resources Management Agent         True           5
Scripting Agent                       False           6
Mailbox Creation Time Agent            True           0
```

Here is my big question,

## Why is this exception not getting caught?

Later in my script, `$ASChangeValue` is still set to 1, as opposed to 8. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Set-CASMailbox`:

```powershell
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $tempUsername -ActiveSyncEnabled $true -ErrorAction Stop
```